# How to change multiple selection view in infopath?

Tags: infopath, multiple-values

In my project i use multiple-selection box. For default sharepoint view its very useful with its link style. But when i try to open it in infopath, it changes to kind of checkbox. How can i make it like link style in infopath ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

- "But when i try to open it in infopath, it changes"  ?

When I open the browser based (aka enabled) Infopath 2010 form with Multiple-Selection List Box in browser through Sharepoint Server 2010's Infopath Form Service, it still has the same checkboxes with the same appearance as in Infopath Designer 210 and in Infopath Filler/client form.

[image]

Then, what is the sense of having links and being diverted from multiple selection on first click?

Also, this does not make sense for Infopath forms permitting and oriented towards:

- off-line (with following synchronization) and/or
- isolated and/or
- etc.

usage, paradigm (philosophy), model and interaction.

Comment: It seems like the picture you shared when we open the form service in infopath. But I want it sharepoints default style(Linked to item).

Comment: Although i open it in infopath.

Comment: There is no difference in Infopath Filler or in browser through Sharepoint Server Infopath Form Services. If you want sharepoint style than use Sharepoint Designer instead of Infopath Designer, as simple as that.

Comment: Ok, i'll try sp designer. I dont know anything about it,lets find out.  Thx